# How to List all the available webservices

Tags: vb.net, web-services, iis, webserver

How can i list all the available webservices by just providing the server name?
I require that i will just specify the server name, and then a list will be populated with names of all the webservices available.

Answer (score 1):

In short, you can't -- unless the server was configured to somehow supply the information.

That is presuming you mean "have the server enumerate what HTTP-bound data applications are running." But you might want to give a few more details as there might be another way around the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As per the requirement , i have no information about the server configuration.

I just have the name of the server on which the webservices are hosted, and just by providing the name i must get all the webservices posted on that server.Further when i select the webservice i must get the list of the operations available on the selected webservice.